# compare items in the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a config file of format:

> IP,username,logfile
>
> IP,username,logfile1
>
> IP,username,logfile2

I am giving code below to store text file lines into a list, but i need help with the code which can determine whether name of logfile is same as logfile1 or not
please help

```
import csv

config_file_path = "config15.txt"  # read config file and assign IP,username,logfile,serverpath,localpath
file  = open(config_file_path, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
all_rows = [row for row in reader] # appending config file contents in a list
```

output above code gives:

```
[['127.0.0.1', 'new34', 'logfile'], ['127.0.0.1', 'new34', 'logfile1']]
```

I want a code that compares and tell if name of `logfile` and `logfile1` same or not and if same return true as output.

Comment: Can you add sample input ad sample output

Comment: @0xPrateek if the name of logfile and logfile1 is same it should return true as output

Comment: By `logfile` and `logfile1` do you mean any two of the filenames, of just the second and third ones in the config file, or something else? What if there are two pairs of filenames equal? What if three filenames are equal?

Comment: @RoryDaulton any two filenames.    i have edited the question for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration and a `set` used as a check variable.

**Ex:**

```
all_rows = [['127.0.0.1', 'new34', 'logfile1'], ['127.0.0.1', 'new34', 'logfile1']]
def check_row(data):
    seen = set()
    for i in data:
        if i[-1] in seen:
            return True
        else:
            seen.add(i[-1])
    return False


print(check_row(all_rows))  #True
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is really yours file format. It would be easier to read it as Data Frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('config15.txt',sep=',', header = None, names =['ip','un','lf']) #or just change extension to *.csv
dupldf =df[df.duplicated(['lf'])]# find duplicate rows
```

if empty, there is not duplicated values

Answer (score 0):

Thus, if I've understood, you are looking for logfile duplicates.
First of all you need a list (or a vector of logfiles), e.g.:

```
logfiles = [row[-1] for row in reader]
```

This list contains the logfile names.
Now, i suggest you to use `numpy`, which is a very large library for python contains usefull methods (if you want code in python you have to know this library), so:

```
import numpy as np
logfiles = np.array(logfiles) #simply transformation of list into a numpy array 
i, j = np.where(logfiles[:, np.newaxis]==logfiles[np.newaxis, :])
```

`logfiles[i]` are the duplicated elements, i.e. `logfiles[i] = logfiles[j]` 
clearly each element is also equal to it self, so you have to delete the elements for which `i==j`:

```
index2save = np.where(i[:, np.newaxis]!=j[np.newaxis, :])[0]
i = i[index2save]
```

Now `i` are the indices of duplicates elements, and `logfiles[i]` are the same names.
Hoping this can help you!